# Click on button is not working which present on top of collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-toolbar

[enter image description here][1]When i add elevation to btn_layout click start working but when i add image in background of btn_layout then toolbar gets hidden below this layout soo elevation is also not helping for me. So how can i handle the click on button without disturbing toolbar in xml. Thank You.

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="showToast"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
                    android:onClick="btnClick"></Button>

            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHCn6.png
````

Comment: have you tried to use `translationZ` instead of `elevation`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because your Toolbar is above LinearLayout (btn_layout) which has the button, so the button is overlapped by the Toolbar.
Change your order to be the Toolbar first and then your LinearLayout and it should solve your issue like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

           <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.PopupOverlay" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="showToast"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
                    android:onClick="btnClick"></Button>
            </LinearLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```